# Spring repository make select by first entity and try mappin to another entity(entity has same names)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entities:

```
package datamodel.serviceone;

@Entity(name = "user")
public class Human{
```

and

```
package datamodel.servicetwo;

@Entity(name = "user")
public class Robot{
```

I have repository:

```
@Repository
public interface HumanRepository extends CrudRepository<Human, Long> {
  Human findOneBySex(String sex);
}
```

But when I try

```
humanRepository.findOneBySex("mail");
```

I get error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: sex of: datamodel.servicetwo.Robot [select generatedAlias0 from datamodel.servicetwo.Robot as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.sex=:param0]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
```

Why???!!! I have 2 entity with same names, and spring not throw exeption like "You have 2 same entity!" but it work and repository return entity, but another entity. In debug mode I see that `humanRepository.findOneBySex("mail");` must return `Human` but this method make select in `Human` and try mapping to `Robot`

Comment: Post your `Human` class and `Robot` class codes too. All properties.

Comment: these are not real classes. the fact is that they have different fields. they have different class names, different packages, stored in different bases. Only the names are the same. In one database there is a table User and in the other database there is a table User. Initially, I made a mistake that I created 2 entities with the same name. but the question is that the repository does not understand and works incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `@Table` annotation. The problem is that you register two entities with the same name instead to bind them to same tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Human
```

And then:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Robot
```

Comment: Yes. I soldev problem just this way. I have not problem with this. But This case made me think and find out why repository work wrong if we use 2 same entity name. it is logical that he should give an error about this. But the error in runtime and it absolutely does not show a problem. She says only that the request can not be mapping with the entity. And does not understand what <RigthEntity> != mappingEntity

Comment: That should work. I'd say hibernate overrides the first entity declaration with the second scanned one, which seems to be the Robot class.

Comment: Hibernate docs state that an entity has to be unique. If you have twice the same class (simplename) it will actually throw an exception at startup. Probably they miss a check if you declare the name with the Entity annotation.

Comment: @ Martin Frey Yes. that's what I mean. I think it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

You are using same table for two different classes, it will get mixed up. How hibernate knows that user table is of human or robot.
Also both classes can have different properties.

Either create two different table or create a super class of `User` and extend `Human` and `Robot` classes from it. Put common attributes in User class.

Comment: each entity storage in separate DB. There are 2 databases  HumanDb and RobotDb. each DB have User table with different fields.

Comment: How are handling two databases inside one hibernate app?

Comment: The question is why the repository in general can work with two entities with the same name and does not fall with an error - "dude! you have two entity with the same names. This will not work."

Comment: I have a module that stores all the entity in separate packages. and each microservice connects this module and uses its entities. Human entity must use in HumanService with HumanDB with Human Datasource.

Comment: As you can see in the error, its still picking up robot from database in hql, its not doing the wrong mapping, spring will not throw error because when it creates tables, it will overwrite one model mapping with otherone. So when when querying human, spring will be considering robot mapping for the user entity

Comment: CrudRepository<Human, Long> - HUMAN! Human findOneBySex(String sex); - return class HUMAN! Hibernate try select in user table HUMAB DB, but maping to ROBOT. and in the service where you need a ROBOT- everything works correctly.

Comment: That's what I'm saying that in table creation the mapping of human is overwritten by mapping of human due to same entity name. So when you query for Robot, spring will have no problem. Also check spring sequence of creating mapping, if it's alphabetical then human mapping will not be available